# Could not load file or assembly "Newtonsoft.Json.Net" (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Tags: c#, json.net, neo4jclient

When we installed a previous version the Neo4jClient via nuget we saw that Newtonsoft.Json version 4.5.0.0 was installed as a dependency. We also use other packages that require version 6.0.0.0 of Newtonsoft.Json and when we install them it overrides version 4.5.0.0.

When we start our app we get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.Ex
ceptionDetail]: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.
0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly referenc
e. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

We looked at all our configs and found nothing referencing version 4.5.0.0, however after taking a closer look at the Neo4jClient we found this.

[image: using ildasm.exe from visual studion tools]

Here is the packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AzureStorageClient" version="0.0.5.1829" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CouchbaseNetClient" version="1.3.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Elasticsearch.Net" version="1.0.0-beta1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.20" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Neo4jClient" version="1.0.0.652" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NEST" version="1.0.0-beta1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

We have removed all packages, reinstalled, cleaned and rebuilt but with no avail.
Is this the Neo4jClient that is causing this to happen or does the problem live somewhere else?

**UPDATE**
What we have tried

1. Removed all packages and re installed
2. Cleaned and rebuilt solution
3. Assembly redirect
4. Tried looking for `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` but was not in the .csproj

Comment: Does it find the assembly itself? So try to set the assembly as: Copy local: true.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti the `Copy Local` was set too `true` by default

Comment: The AutoGenerateBindingRedirects is not there by default, you can just add it to the csproj file

Comment: @ChrisSkardon Even after adding it it still does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried assembly version redirect via app.config/web.config?

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Yes, funny thing though is that I have two projects in the solution. One being the code and the other the tests. The tests added a `app.config` and the main project only has a `packages.config`, which does not include the `<bindingRedirect>`.

Comment: Then try to add the app.config/web.config file manually and paste the redirect in there?

Comment: While this might be an answer to my case, it does not explain WHY? Why do I need to do binding-redirect voodoo? I'll try it now...

Comment: @Mzn: This is required, because some referenced projects (`Neo4jClient` in the OPs case) rewuired an older version of the `Newtonsoft.Json` library, but as you can not load two different versions the "old reference" is "redirected to the new version".

Comment: If adding the assemblyBinding didn't work, make sure that your web.config's configuration tag (at the top) does NOT contain the xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0" attribute.